# ¿Existe la palabra recíproca de "uxoricida"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, antónimos

[**Uxoricida**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bDYozQT) es:

> Del lat. *uxor, -ōris* 'mujer, esposa' y *-cida*.
>   1. m. Hombre que mata a su mujer. U. t. c. adj.

¿Existe la palabra recíproca, que describe a la "mujer que mata a su marido"?

Answer (score 4):

La verdad es que es la primera vez que oigo ese término, lo desconocía. Buscando en el DIRAE no he encontrado ninguna palabra cuya raíz sea *virum* (marido) o *sponsum* (esposo), así que para el caso contrario habrá que tirar de términos más genéricos, como *homicida* o **[conyugicida](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AiBRMid)**.

Buscando términos más coloquiales que no aparecen en el diccionario, uno podría ser [viuda negra](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viuda_negra_(asesina)), pero este término define a un tipo concreto de mujeres que asesinan a sus maridos en serie, y motivadas principalmente por motivos económicos.

Curiosamente, en inglés sí que existe el opuesto: [mariticide](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariticide). En español sería "mariticidio", que no está recogido oficialmente pero si lo buscas en Google verás textos que emplean esa palabra.